# Vuejs equivalent of jquery-cron

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

does anybody know an equivalent of jquery-cron (https://github.com/shawnchin/jquery-cron) with similar, very simple, text/select interface?

I have seen vue-cron and point-vue-cron but they are too complex.

Comment: @JaromandaX is it supposed to help?

Comment: well maybe you should check them. there is no simpler interface than jquery cron and you can barely do more complex than vue-cron, and if I ask the question is maybe someone would have a constructive comment and I would not need to write one or use jquery.

Comment: I read both and came to my conclusion ... sorry if my opinion somehow offended you

Comment: I m not offended, I just try to point your comments are not helping toward my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[vue-js-cron](https://github.com/abichinger/vue-js-cron) is inspired by [jqcron](https://github.com/arnapou/jqcron), which is very similar to jquery-cron.

A demo can be found [here](https://abichinger.github.io/vue-js-cron/demo.html).

Disclaimer: I am the developer of [vue-js-cron](https://github.com/abichinger/vue-js-cron)

Comment: looks good @abichinger, although the UI part requires vuetify?

Comment: For now, vuetify is the only supported UI framework, but I plan to support more in the future.
If you would like to use other UI elements, you can opt for the [renderless component](https://abichinger.github.io/vue-js-cron/guide/getting-started.html#quick-start-renderless).

Comment: **Update**: I just added [@vue-js-cron/light](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue-js-cron/light), which does not require a UI framework.

Comment: neat, thanks for it

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [vue-cron-editor](https://github.com/dwainbrowne/vue-cron-editor) it has the best UI i've seen so far, might get you halfway there.

*disclaimer, I haven't actually used this yet, just found it during my search.

Comment: thanks @DwainBrowne, it is still quite busier than the one I m looking for.

Comment: Agreed but it's a decent start. I'm going to be working on one in the coming weeks, will share my update once it's ready.